# Setting timeout for WCF Dataservice

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services, odata, asp.net-web-api

I was struggling with some timeouts for an OData service. My first idea was to change the timeout property but I could not find the correct place to do this. Where should be the request timeout set and how?, is there any best practice?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the ODataClient (DataServiceContext), it has a Timeout property that one can set. If you are using your own client, then it depends on what technology you are using to send the request - HttpWebClient, HttpListener, HttpClient, etc. They all have properties to set appropriate Timeout.

Hope this helps.
Thanks
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about an OData service, but normally the send and receive timeout properties are set on the binding itself. I use BasicHTTPBinding for my web service and, on the host, the binding is set this way (in code):

```
BasicHttpBinding b = default(BasicHttpBinding);
b = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
dynamic specialTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
b.CloseTimeout = specialTimeSpan;
b.ReceiveTimeout = specialTimeSpan;
b.SendTimeout = specialTimeSpan;
b.OpenTimeout = specialTimeSpan;
```

So that would set the close, open, receive and send timeouts to 30 minutes.

In a config file deployment, it would be something like this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding 
   closeTimeout="00:30:00" 
   openTimeout="00:30:00" 
   receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
   sendTimeout="00:30:00"
```